# Embed object for mp3 not playing

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Recently I had to replace a sound notifications module for a web application for IE8. It was done with Flash and was giving as a whole lot of problems.

The new way to reproduce those sounds is through `embed` tags, like this one:

```
<embed id='player-msg' hidden='true' autoplay='true' 
       src='../../App_Themes/Operator/sounds/ding.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>
```

Then we try to play it like this:

```
document.getElementById('player-msg').play();
```

It doesn't work. Or at least not in all the computers, which is bad enough.

It always work when I append the embed with autoplay though:

```
var embed = $("<embed id='player-msg' hidden='true' autoplay='true'
    src='../../App_Themes/Operator/sounds/ding.mp3' type='audio/mp3'/>");
$("body").append(embed);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well that's strange: you'd need `$("body").append(embed);`. (`$` is missing.)

Comment: Anyways, an `<embed>` element could be anything and doesn't have an API. This is why there is HTML5 audio now. You should probably go back to using Flash. Or, if a delay is okay, append a new element with `autoplay` each time.